# Match word containing 1 or more numbers AND zero or more letters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex statement that will match any word containing 1 or more numbers and (optionally) any capital letters in that same word. This is where I'm at right now:

```
\w[A-Z]*[0-9]+
```

This of course is matching if it starts with letters and ends with numbers, but not something like "70053105P" where the number follows the letter. In the end I would need it to match something like A1A1A1A1A1... etc., but not AAAAAAAA.

I've thought about doing `[A-Z0-9]+` but that will match 0 or more numbers, and I need it to have 1 or more.

Comment: Do you wish match words that contain zero or more capital letters, one or more digits and no other characters? (That is inconsistent with your regex, however.) If the word is to contain only word characters there’s no point mentioning optional capital letters. Please clarify by editing.

Comment: The choice of answer makes clear what is wanted: "Match strings comprised of word characters that are preceded by and followed by a word break and that contain at least one digit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match 0 or more occurrences of a word char except for a digit. Then match a digit and 0+ occurrences of a word char surrounded with word boundaries.

```
\b[^\W0-9]*[0-9]\w*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[^\W0-9]*` Match 0+ occurrences of a word char except a digit
- `[0-9]` Match a digit
- `\w*` Match 0+ word chars
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PNFvQn/1)

Comment: That's the one! Thanks

Comment: Is this not the same as `\b\w*[0-9]\w*\b`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland It will get the same match, but using `[^\W0-9]*` prevents backtracking as `\w` also matches a digit.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
([A-Z]*\d+[A-Z]*)+
```

This matches 0 or more characters before or after at least one number, and requires this sequence to repeat at least once.